# Building a deterministic wallet without random seed phrase instead multiple static inputs

Tags: wallets, private-key, hd-wallets, hash-algorithm

If I want to be able to create a private key given inputs x,y,z and these inputs are constant, if I add enough entropy as a salt would it be secure to create a key this way (in terms of brute force attacks or reverse engineering) and be able to re constitute it given the same inputs where the salt also never changes, pseudo code
where x,y,z are

```
val salt = "4D6250655368566D597133743677397A"
val output = SHA256(salt + x + y + z)
```

and recursively hash the output 100,000x sort of like using 3 passwords

Answer (score 1):

It will be as secure as trying to decrypt passwords with a constant salt. You can use whatever source of entropy you want, but if your salt gets published you'll have problems, specially for those users whose `x`, `y` and `z` are easily guessable via dictionary attack.

That being said, I'm not saying it's a bad solution, I just pretended to remark that it's definitely possible, but there are more secure options. It depends on you particular needs.

A stronger solution would be to generate a random salt for each user, being this salt stored on a different database than your users' data, and if possible in a different machine.

Comment: Yeah I understand the security risks, the salt would never be committed to source code, x y z are UUID's so they are not human readable words. Per your last comment on salt per user, the idea is to have a sort of stateless / databaseless storage system. No database to compromise, only source code, hence a deterministic approach.

Comment: Well, if `x`, `y` and `z` are UUIDs I think you are fine.